# Maintain database.yml on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a Rails 4 app version controlled with git.

I would like to have a version of database.yml on my server that never changes. What's the best way to allow me to continue to edit this file locally, without changing the remote database.yml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include your local version of database.yml in .gitignore, so that it's not in the repository and won't change with subsequent deployments.

For instance, in your application root, create a ".gitignore" file and add the following in:

config/database.yml

You can also hide entire directories:

config/*

Basic shell wildcard syntax will work.

*.sql

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take it out of version control, it shouldn't be there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We don't track our config/database.yml in version control (we do track a sample file so it's easier to get setup on new development machines). Our deployment script symlinks in a custom database.yml that's stored in the application user's home directory with permissions set to "600". This way the app user is the only user that can see the database password, and we don't have to do anything manual on deploy.

Answer (score 0):

move database.yml to some secure folder, like /etc/config/database.yml and then create symlink 
 of that file with rails database.yml after deployment but before starting server.